# How can I improve my code to find replays in a string?

Tags: arrays, swift, permutation, replay

My task was to determine how many correct words of a given length N exist. Only those that do not have any repetitions of sequences of characters in a row are considered correct words, I will post an example below. Alafit words consists of the symbols a, b, c. (Lower case). I decided to generate all combinations of characters for a given length. Then I wrote the search function for the right words. The code works correctly. But I have doubts that my approach was correct. Maybe I can somehow optimize this code, or should I use other ways to achieve the result?

Example:

```
The specified word length: 3, the number of correct words: 12
        Correct words:
        ["aba", "abc", "aca", "acb", "bab", "bac", "bca", "bcb", "cab", "cac", "cba", "cbc"]

        Wrong words:
        ["aaa", "aab", "aac", "abb", "acc", "baa", "bba", "bbb", "bbc", "bcc", "caa", "cbb", "cca", "ccb", "ccc"]
```

My code:

```
import Foundation

func findRepetition(_ p: String) -> [String:Int] {
    var repDict: [String:Int] = [:]
    var p = p
    while p.count != 0 {
        for i in 0...p.count-1 {
            repDict[String(Array(p)[0..<i]), default: 0] += 1
        }
        p = String(p.dropFirst())
    }
    return repDict
}

var correctWords = [String]()
var wrongWords = [String]()
func getRepeats(_ p: String) -> Bool {
    let p = p
    var a = findRepetition(p)
    for i in a {
        var substring = String(Array(repeating: i.key, count: 2).joined())
        if p.contains(substring) {
            wrongWords.append(p)
            return false
        }
    }
    correctWords.append(p)
    return true
}

var counter = 0
func allLexicographicRecur (_ string: [String.Element], _ data: [String], _ last: Int, _ index: Int){
    var length = string.count-1
    var data = data
    for i in 0...length {
        data[index] = String(string[i])
        if index == last {
            if getRepeats(data.joined()) {
                counter += 1
            }
        }else{
            allLexicographicRecur(string, data, last, index+1)
        }

    }
}


func threeLanguage(_ l: Int) {
    var alphabet = "abc"
    var data = Array(repeating: "", count: l)
    allLexicographicRecur(alphabet.sorted(), data, l-1, 0)
    print("The specified word length: \(l), the number of correct words: \(counter)\n")
    print("Correct words:\n\(correctWords)\n")
    print("Wrong words:\n\(wrongWords)")
}


threeLanguage(3)
```

I also have difficulties with estimating the complexity of the algorithm (big O). Since at the moment the program consists of functions whose complexity is different. Some have O (n²), and some have O (n). I would also be very grateful for the clarification of this point.

Comment: Instead of generating an entire list of all combinations, why don't you add some intelligence to your word list generator so that it never allows characters to repeat?  Then compare the performance results.

Comment: AgRizzo, I do not know how to add intelligence to the generation of words, except for the existing function of checking words for the presence of getRepeats () repetitions.

Comment: This can be solved mathematically.  When generating a word of length 3 from 3 possible symbols (a, b, c) - you have 3 choices for the first letter, 2 for the second (can't repeat the first), and 2 for the third (can't repeat the second).  So there are 3 * 2 * 2 = 12 possible words without repeats of the prior letter.  And total words is 3 * 3 * 3 = 27, so there are 27 - 12 = 15 invalid words.

Comment: vacawama, The specified length can be 6 characters. For example, abcabc is also the wrong word (there is a repetition of the sequence "abc" here). Is your formula able to find the right number in this case?